# Load Testing Site with OWIN authentication

Tags: c#, .net, owin, performance-testing

[ C#.Net, Visual Studio , Web Performance Test ]

Hi, I am a newbie to Load testing and OWIN Authentication.

Recently we converted our site to use OWIN authentication instead of Forms Authentication which broke our load test scripts.

1. I ran load test scripts and sent the same request (which is failing in the load test script) through post man and it did not work.
2. When i checked the load test logs, for which i was making a web api call, i found that, the cookies are missing and hence I am getting a response message as "Authorization has been denied for this request"
3. I downloaded postman interceptor and postman , to use the "cookies"
   I captured the network headers for a working request(from production) and added the "Cookie" header to the Post man request and it worked !!
4. I tried to capture last response from and save those cookie values to assign for the next request.

But, the cookies are read only :(((

I want to know, if there is a way to persist those cookies between requests ?

I have gone through lot of sites but, nothing has helped to resolve the issue i am facing. Can any one help me?

Template of the Web Api Class (if it helps):

```
[Authorize]
public class FabricomApiController : WebApiController
{
    public FabricomApiController()
    {
      // Constructor
    }    

    [HttpPost]
    public Response PostFabricom(Request request1)
    {
         try
            {
               // Builds a request and sends a request.
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
               // Logs Exception
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: Where do you want to persist the cookie? In Postman, browser or on the server-side?

Comment: When i record tests, it generated few calls and those calls require authentication. 
Suppose, I hit sign in then, OWIN sets up the cookie (because we are using cookie authentication), This cookie is not carried forward for next request, say i want to access admin page or any signed in page.
i want to bypass the [Authorize] for the requests

Comment: I understood your wish. The question is: are you using browser or some REST client? Who you expect to carry cookies?

Comment: I would like to carry those in all the requests once the authentication is done. I haven't seen anything like a real browser when i run the scripts.